# How can I inspect network traffic from a GPRS watch?

Tags: embedded, gprs, software-defined-radio

I recently received a one of these Chinese watches that communicates over GPRS.  I am trying to decipher the protocol used, as well as trying to figure out why it does not work.

I was thinking that there might be various approaches to inspecting the network traffic in this case.

- Maybe there is a 3G/GSM operator that lets me inspect the network traffic? (does this exist?)
- Create a fake base-station using software defined radio (seems incredibly overkill)
- Maybe some other trick can work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPRS is what I'd call an extension to GSM. As that, it's encrypted.

So simply sniffing airborne traffic won't do. It's possible, though not overly likely, that [your network operator uses weak encryption](https://youtu.be/fH_fXSr-FhU) ([slides](https://events.ccc.de/congress/2010/Fahrplan/attachments/1783_101228.27C3.GSM-Sniffing.Nohl_Munaut.pdf)), but deciphering GPRS traffic might be a bit much if you haven't done something like that before. Hence, your two approaches sound reasonable.

> - Maybe there is a 3G/GSM operator that lets me inspect the network traffic? (does this exist?)

No. At least, I don't think so (and on some level, I hope they don't. The potential for abuse is just too high).

However, you *could* be your own operator, as you notice yourself:

> - Create a fake base-station using software defined radio (seems incredibly overkill)

How's that overkill? You want to play man in the middle in a complex infrastructure. Becoming infrastructure does sound like the logical next step.

As a matter of fact, Osmocom's [OpenBSC](http://openbsc.osmocom.org/trac/) freshly supports GPRS modes. You can program your own sim card and use it, without faking anything, within your own network. It's noteworthy that under any jurisdiction I can think of, you'll need a spectrum license to operate a mobile phone network, so you should only do this within a well-shielded enclosure.

Another approach that sounds far more viable and financially sound: Disassemble one watch, look out for the different ICs/modules, identify whether there's an isolated GPRS modem. Find the serial lines between that and your watch's CPU, and tap electrically into that with a <10USD serial-to-USB converter. Out of curiosity, I think we'd all like to know which model you got from where :D